# SQL command that creates a database

Tags: mysql, sql

Write an SQL command that creates a database that has the following structure:

Table 2: Name: StaffDetails

Screenshot of Structure: [Table Structure](https://ibb.co/iHoKgk)

```
CREATE DATABASE StaffDetails_database;
USE StaffDetails _database;

CREATE TABLE StaffDetails (
  StaffRef INT NOT NULL,
  LName NCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  FName NCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  Phone NCHAR(25) NULL,
  StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (StaffRef),
  );
```

Would this be correct way to create this?

Comment: Is it for mysql or sql-server?

Comment: No, there are typoes. Please just run the thing to see if it does the right thing.

Comment: This is for MySQL

Comment: As @Mat suggested, you should just run it in the IDE, and you will get some (helpful) errors. From there, it should be simple enough for you to fix the issues.

Comment: *[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)*: not everyone has both a forename and surname.

Comment: `Use` is not a keyword in that sense that it would be understood by the server. It is a hint for any IDE supporting it to switch the database connection. In a client API, you'll need to call mysqli_select_db or something similar.

Comment: In the use-statement there is a blank between `Staffdetails` and `_details`

Comment: The syntax is fine for MySQL. If you aren’t sure of the statements, then better use any GUI clients like [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) which will help you debug the syntax errors.